# View Pager se demora en poner imagenes con Picasso

Tags: android

En mi mainActivity tengo esto

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this);
viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
```

Esta es la declaracion del xml donde se encuentra el viewPager

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
```

Este es mi adaptador:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Integer [] images = {R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c, R.drawable.d, R.drawable.e, R.drawable.g, R.drawable.i, R.drawable.j};

public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slider_show, null);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    Picasso.with(context).load(images[position]).fit().into(imageView);

    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
    vp.addView(view, 0);
    return view;

}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
    View view = (View) object;
    vp.removeView(view);

}
}
```

Quiero saber porque al pasar las fotos me muestra una imagen en blanco y despues es que carga la foto? No hay alguna manera que el viewPager cargue las imagenes parecido a una aplicacion de fotos? Necesito ayuda por favor no he podido descifrar que es y me estoy volviendo loco. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas usando un `ViewPager` debes tomar en cuenta que no todas las vistas definidas en el pager se encuentran cargadas, si se realizará esto y aún mas cargando imágenes en cada pagina podría causar problemas de memoria.

Por default solo carga una vista, si quieres aumentar las páginas que son precargadas puedes usar el método **[setOffscreenPageLimit()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))**

Como ejemplo puedes precargar 5 paginas, la actual dos a la izquierda y dos a la derecha, se realizaría de esta forma:

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
```

Obviamente la cantidad debe ser igual o menor a la cantidad de paginas en el pager. Con esto evitarías un poco el hecho de ver paginas sin la imagen al paginar.

---

Es recomendable también implementar guardado a disco de las imágenes, con esto evitarías ver el cargado desde internet de las imágenes cada vez que se instancia una pagina ya que el acceso a disco es más rápido.

Agrego un ejemplo de lo que comento usando la última versión de Picasso que ahora no requiere el contexto. Primeramente define 
`.networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)` para determinar si la imagen existe en el disco, en caso de no existir, la descarga de internet:

```
Picasso.get().load(urlImage).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(imageView, new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                Log.i(TAG, "Load image from caché! " + urlImage);
                textView.setText("From Caché:\n " + Uri.parse(urlImage).getLastPathSegment());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onError() " + e.getMessage());
                Log.i(TAG, "Try to load image from internet! " + urlImage);               
                //Can´t find image in cache, load from internet.
                Picasso.get().load(urlImage).into(imageView);

            }
        });
```

Comment: Mañana la pruebo y te doy solución aceptada si me funciona el método gracias x la ayuda

Comment: @AlexRivas acabo de actualizar mi respuesta con un ejemplo para guardar a cache las imagenes y obtenerla para una carga mas rápida de la imagen.

Comment: las imagenes son locales o sea estan dentro de la apk... eso cambia algo??

Comment: papa eres un crack funciona de maravilla

Comment: Excellente me alegro te ayuda esta información, saludos @AlexRivas

Comment: ayudame otra vez, le puse mas fotos y le aumente el offScreenPageLimit en 11 y me muestra todas las img excepto la primera y otra, y cuando entro a otro activty y regreso se detiene la apk...

Comment: @AlexRivas al iniciar la carga de la pagina en cuestion puede ser que tarde ya que esta instanciando esta y las demás páginas, agregar 11 paginas implica que estarán en memoria, si se detiene posiblemente es por las imágenes que estas cargando pueden no estar optmizadas, ser de tamaño considerable.

Comment: le puse 5 y funciona perfecto pero pasa lo q te digo a veces se queda en blanco cuando entro a otro activity y demora mas tiempo q lo normal en cargar no hay alguna manera de mantener esas fotos en cache como hace google fotos??

Comment: hay un problema mas grande aun, tengo varias activitys pero cuando entro a la del correo que es una activity con un webView y luego vuelvo al main que es donde se encuentra el viewPager las fotos no son las mismas me pone fotos de iconos que tengo dentro de apk, otras me salen en blanco y 2 solamente me salen correctas que pasa ahi??? Espero que me puedas responder @Jorgesys voy a editar la pregunta y poner la activity del correo y replantear la pregunta

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80143/discussion-between-jorgesys-and-alex-rivas).